# Knee brace support hold down bracket for treehouse

Tags: treehouse

I cannot seem to find the right bracket to use as a hold down on the tree side for a treehouse knee brace beam.  I need to find one that can bolted to the tree and hold two 2x8's. It looks just like this but I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

Also, how do you attach the knee braces to the corners of the platform? There seems to be various ways of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you define "anywhere" ?   No luck at HomeDepot, Amazon, ?

Comment: No luck at Home depot, just cheap framing brackets there.  No luck on Amazon finding the right size.  Lowes had something similar but not exactly right.

Comment: See http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/66002/knee-brace-support-hanger-for-treehouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too hard -- the page I suspect you got that photo calls it a "hold-down bracket,"  and that exact part appears to be available [here, fastenersplus.com](http://www.fastenersplus.com/Simpson-HD3B-Bolted-Holdown-G90-Galvanized?gclid=COCxovG36c4CFQ9bhgode-MJRw)

[image: the bracket]

I'll take my finder's fee in chocolate :-)

Comment: WOW, I have looked up and down for this!  Where do I send the chocolate!!!   I assume 2.5 inches wide will hold two 2x8's?   THANK YOU!!!

Comment: 2-1/2" won't be great for 2-2x8, as you'd have to remove 1/2" of material (thus weakening the support). Better would be 2 brackets with slices of 1/2" ply padding out the 2x material.

Comment: @chiltonjh  If this works out for you, please mark the answer as accepted.  Thanks!